# Select element of list based on proximity to a certain value

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following matrix:

```
data = {{0.795718, 0.737, 0.813, 1.27301}, {0.846782, 0.767, 0.86,1.2859}, 
  {0.742211, 0.691, 0.767, 1.27714}, {0.754719, 0.706, 0.783,1.27319},  
  {0.743044, 0.691, 0.783, 1.26768}, {0.745167, 0.706,0.783, 1.28189},  
  {0.815733, 0.752, 0.86,1.25376}, {0.551127, 0.553,0.553, 1.2084}};
```

each row is made up of a list of 4 elements: `{x1,x2,x3,y}`. I would like to apply a rule to the matrix that allows me to select, row by row, only one of the first 3 elements, the one that is closest to a certain value, let us say `xbest` (eg 0.8 in the example with the data above), let us call this element `xwin`. Eventually, I would like have a new matrix with rows of 2 elements only: `{xwin,y}`.
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a good case for [`NearestTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestTo.html):

> NearestTo[*x*]
>       is an operator form that yields Nearest[*elems*, *x*] when applied to a list *elems*.

```
nTo = NearestTo[xbest, 1];
Join[nTo /@ data[[All, ;; 3]], data[[All, {4}]], 2]
```

> {{0.795718, 1.27301}, {0.767, 1.2859}, {0.767, 1.27714}, {0.783, 1.27319}, {0.783, 1.26768}, {0.783, 1.28189}, {0.815733, 1.25376}, {0.553, 1.2084}}

Comment: Nice! I didn't know of this new function! Do you know how does it compare with Nearest in terms of efficiency?

Comment: @Fraccalo, it seems that for long lists they are similar, but shorter lists, to my surprise,  `Nearest` is much faster: `dt=RandomInteger[100000,s];
NearestTo[99]@dt// RepeatedTiming` versus `Nearest[dt, 99]// RepeatedTiming ` for `s=100` and `s = 10^6`.

Comment: I am using v10.0 and `NearestTo` is not defined there. How to circumvent this? and how to get the element (from the first 3) that is the furthest away from `xBest`?

Comment: @Luigi, `NearestTo` is new in v11.3. I would go with Fraccalo's answer for finding  nearest and farthest elements.

Comment: @kglr Thanks for the benchmark! And yes, the discrepancy in the speed depending on the list length is quite weird

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
xBest = 0.8;
{First@Nearest[#[[1 ;; 3]], xBest], #[[4]]} & /@ data
```

And for the "Farthest" function:

```
xBest = 0.8;
{First@Nearest[#[[1 ;; 3]], xBest, 
     DistanceFunction -> (-Abs[#1 - #2] &)], #[[4]]} & /@ data
```

Comment: could work! however, if you apply it to `data`, you see that the last row has duplicated value (3 elements rather than 2). With `xBest=0.8058` you get `{{0.813, 1.27301}, {0.767, 1.2859}, {0.767, 1.27714}, {0.783, 
  1.27319}, {0.783, 1.26768}, {0.783, 1.28189}, {0.815733, 
  1.25376}, {0.553, 0.553, 1.2084}}` as result.

Comment: Check the last edit :D

Comment: Now, how to select the element that is furthest away from `xBest`. In other words, what is the opposite of `Nearest`? thanks!

Comment: See new edit to my answer

Answer (score 2):

**Using `TakeLargestBy` and `TakeSmallestBy`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
xbest = 0.8;

data = {{0.795718, 0.737, 0.813, 1.27301}, {0.846782, 0.767, 0.86, 
    1.2859}, {0.742211, 0.691, 0.767, 1.27714}, {0.754719, 0.706, 
    0.783, 1.27319}, {0.743044, 0.691, 0.783, 1.26768}, {0.745167, 
    0.706, 0.783, 1.28189}, {0.815733, 0.752, 0.86, 
    1.25376}, {0.551127, 0.553, 0.553, 1.2084}};

nearest = 
  TakeSmallestBy[EuclideanDistance[#, xbest] &, 1] /@ 
   data[[All, 1 ;; 3]];
last = data[[All, {4}]];
farthest = 
  TakeLargestBy[EuclideanDistance[#, xbest] &, 1] /@ 
   data[[All, 1 ;; 3]];

MapThread[Join, {nearest, last}]
MapThread[Join, {farthest, last}]
```

---

*Results:*

> {{0.795718, 1.27301}, {0.767, 1.2859}, {0.767, 1.27714}, {0.783,
> 1.27319}, {0.783, 1.26768}, {0.783, 1.28189}, {0.815733,
> 1.25376}, {0.553, 1.2084}}
>
> {{0.737, 1.27301}, {0.86, 1.2859}, {0.691, 1.27714}, {0.706,
> 1.27319}, {0.691, 1.26768}, {0.706, 1.28189}, {0.86,
> 1.25376}, {0.551127, 1.2084}}